# How to increase or decrease space between two lines in same paragraph?

Tags: css

Question says everything. How to do it with CSS?

I have also created a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sendmetamil/jn3Vw/).

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/c2EXt/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the line-height!

ie:

```
p {
line-height:20px;
}
```

Comment: Didn't see your answer, I voted to delete mine. PS: weird we both thought about the same code :)

Comment: worth noting this affects an inline box, so works with  a <div> and not a <span>, for example.

Answer (score 2):

Use `line-height`

```
.test{
    line-height:40px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/jn3Vw/1/

You can set the value to anything: percentage or number, which will be multiplied by the `font` value or you can use a measurement like `px` or `em`.

See more here: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/line-height

Answer (score 0):

use line-height property

line-height:100% or line-height:200%